# How to move the contents of TArray

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

In C++ I can do

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v) : _v(std::move(v)) {}
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> _v;
}
```

How can I achieve something similar with ue4 types (`TArray`, `TUniquePtr`), i.e. how to move the contents of `TArray`?

---

Complete example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
class MyObj {};
class A {
 public:
  A(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObj>> v) : _v(std::move(v)) {}
  auto GetV() { return _v.front().get(); }

 private:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObj>> _v;
};

int main() {
  auto v = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObj>>();
  v.push_back(std::make_unique<MyObj>());
  A a(std::move(v));
  assert(a.GetV());
}
```

Comment: By doing it! Did you encounter some problem? You should explain what that problem is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Problem is, that ue4 recommends to use its classes instead of std (despite std compiles and runs on most platforms with ue4) and it was not obvious to me if and which classes it has as replacement for the std ones as stated in the question.

Comment: Did you try it to see what happened? Did you get some error? Did something not happen that you expected?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, it worked well with `std`. But sticking to the [Coding standard of a code base](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/Development/CodingStandard) is as even as important, since a single developer can't oversee the implications on the whole program (works on my machine(s) isn't a good reasoning) - if you want to have more discussion, please hit me on chat.

Comment: I'm asking you to make your question on-topic by actually telling us what the problem is with using the Unreal types and move semantics. If you can't do that, it's off-topic and may be closed!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The topic is that I didn't know (at the time of asking) if I can move the contents of an `TArray` and how to achieve that, which the question `how to move the contents of TArray?` expresses. In the question, nowhere is stated that this is about a problem with UE4 types nor their move semantics, just a lack of knowledge.

Comment: Then the question is off-topic until such time as you have read the documentation (Brennan showed that the answer is found trivially in the `TArray` reference), had a go at achieving your goal, and [encountered an actual practical problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) with said attempt. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. :-)

Comment: No problem, and good luck!

Answer (score 5):

`TArray` has a move constructor (i.e., a constructor whose signature is `TArray(TArray &&other)`) as can be seen [here](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TArray/__ctor/5/index.html).

So `std::move` should work on `TArray` the same way as it does on `std::vector`.

Comment: `TUniquePtr` also has a move constructor: `TUniquePtr(TUniquePtr && Other)`

Answer (score 4):

To complete [the answer of Brennan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55820277/4566599):

C++ std -> UE4 equivalent:

- `std::vector` -> `TArray`
- `std::unique_ptr` -> `TUniquePtr`
- `std::make_unique` -> `MakeUnique`
- `std::move` -> `MoveTempIfPossible` (use `MoveTemp` to get compile time checks for rvalues and const)

So the code example from above with native UE4 classes would look like

```
class MyObj {};
class A {
 public:
  A(TArray<TUniquePtr<MyObj>> v) : _v(MoveTemp(v)) {}
  auto GetV() { return _v[0].Get(); }

 private:
  TArray<TUniquePtr<MyObj>> _v;
};

int main() {
  auto o = MyObj{};
  auto v = TArray<TUniquePtr<MyObj>>();
  v.Add(MakeUnique<MyObj>(o));
  A a(MoveTemp(v));
  assert(a.GetV());
}
```